# pandas bar plot xlabel based on two column values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

given the code below, I get the expected plot attached.
Is there a way to get pandas to plot the X labels as a combination of A and B?
I've tried passing in `x=['A','B']` as well as `x=('A','B')` which does not work...

I would like the labels just to include both of them.
It is possible to pivot and get a semi-workable solution but I don't want to actually compare the subset B side by side...
`df.pivot(index='B',columns='A',values='Val').plot(kind='bar')`

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','Val'])

for a in range(2):
    for b in range(3):
        df = df.append({'A':str(a),'B':str(b),'Val':a+b},ignore_index=True)
        
df.plot(kind='bar',x='B',y='Val')
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiindex by setting columns `A` and `B` as index then use `plot` with `kind=bar`:

```
df.set_index(['A', 'B']).plot(kind='bar', y='Val')
```

---

[image]